# ASMX Web Service - Return user defined class with properties

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx, user-defined-types

Hey,
I am trying to return a user defined class from a web method. The class has properties and/or methods.
Given the following web method:

```
[WebMethod]  
public List<MenuItem> GetMenu()  
{  
    List<MenuItem> menuItemList = new List<MenuItem>();  
    menuItemList.Add(new MenuItem());  
    menuItemList.Add(new MenuItem());  
    menuItemList.Add(new MenuItem());  
    return menuItemList;  
}
```

Now, suppose this web service is consumed by adding a web reference in a newly created console application. The following code is used to test it:

```
public void TestGetMenu()  
{  
    MenuService service = new MenuService.MenuService();  
    service.MenuItem[] menuItemList = service.GetMenu();  
    for (int i = 0; i < menuItemList.Length; i++)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(menuItemList[i].name);  
    }  
    Console.ReadKey();  
}
```

First of all, this doesn't work if the MenuItem class contains properties... Also, if the MenuItem class contains a method the call to the web method doesn't fail, but the method is not in the generated proxy class.. for example: menuItemList[i].getName() does not exist. Why? What am i missing?

```
//This works  
public class MenuItem  
{  
    public string name;  
    public MenuItem()  
    {  
        name = "pizza";  
    }  
}



//This crashes / doesnt work  
public class MenuItem  
{  
    private string name;  
    public MenuItem()  
    {  
        name = "pizza";  
    }  
    public string Name  
    {  
        get { return name; }  
        set { name = value; }  
    }  
}



//This successfully calls web method, but the method does not exist during test  
public class MenuItem  
{  
    private string name;  
    public MenuItem()  
    {  
        name = "pizza";  
    }  
    public string getName()  
    {  
        return name;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: to format code here just indent it 4 spaces, don't wrap it in <code> blocks.  there is a little button which you can use to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you, it was really starting to annoy me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will only work if the class is serializable which usually means public fields and properties, this is why your MenuItem will fail because your `client` side has no idea how to construct the MenuItem class properly.

Try this:

```
[Serializable]
public class MenuItem
{
   private string name;

   public MenuItem()
   {
      name = "pizza";
   }

   public string Name
   {
      get {
         return name;
      }
      set {
         name = value;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked... 
P.s. Stackoverflow community is so good. YES... Finally...

Answer (score 0):

1. private properties are not sent to the client if I remember right.
2. Methods cannot be generated on the client.  What is a method used some resources on the server?
   2a.  To work around this, you can use partial classes to reimplement some of the methods.