# Webservice Best way to return multiple columns from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have an asmx webservice with several methods that reads data from an SQL database.this works fine, but when i want to return data from a table with multiple columns(maybe 4-5) i have some difficulties. i have tested instance of a class as return, and struct also, but this becomes a bit complex on client side with large data. I've also seen in different posts that datatable as return type is not good. So what is the best practice when returnng large data in multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Serailzable calss and return the list of that classes instad
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839637/asmx-web-service-return-user-defined-class-with-properties) can be helpful

Comment: What do you mean by `Serailzable calss`. AFAIK,Other than BinaryFormatter;  SoapFormatter, XmlSerializer, DataContactSerializer, DataContractJsonSerializer, JavascriptSerializer, Json.Net, ServiceStack etc. do not require anything special.